# display input elements from jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project where user can add records, on the add record page user has 1 html form with 10 fields in it. And a button to add more forms with all the 10 fields.

Now, 4 out of 10 fields has auto complete feature of bootstrap typeahead, and the typeahead suggestions works on the default 1st form.

The problem comes when user adds new form on a add-more button click, the form in actually prepared using jquery below:

```
    var wrapper = '<div class="span6"><input type="hidden" name="count[]"  value="' + count + '"/><div class="widget-box"><div class="widget-title"> <span class="fa"> <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> </span> <h5>Add Parent - ' + count + '</h5><button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" id="remove">Remove</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" id="add">Add</button></div><div class="widget-content nopadding">';
    wrapper += '<div class="control-group"> <label class="control-label">First Name</label> <div class="controls"> <input class="span10" type="text" name="firstname[]" id="firstname"> </div></div>';
    wrapper += '<div class="control-group"> <label class="control-label">Last Name</label> <div class="controls"> <input class="span10" type="text" name="lastname[]" id="lastname"> </div></div>';
    wrapper += '<div class="control-group"> <label class="control-label">Gender</label> <div class="controls"> <select class="span10" name="gender[]" id="gender"> <option value="Male">Male</option> <option value="Female">Female</option> </select> </div></div>';
    wrapper += '<div class="control-group"> <label class="control-label">Email Address</label> <div class="controls"> <input class="span10" type="email" name="email[]" id="email"> </div></div>';
    wrapper += '<div class="control-group"> <label class="control-label">Password</label> <div class="controls"> <input class="span10" type="password" name="password[]" id="password" autocomplete="new-password"> </div></div>';

    //typeahead input comes here.......

    wrapper += '</div></div></div>';
    $current_row.append(wrapper);
```

the above code does not include the typeahead inputs which I had previously like below:

```
   wrapper += '<div class="control-group"> 
                 <label class="control-label">Hobby</label> 
                 <div class="controls"> 
                   <input type="text" class="typeahead span10" name="hobby[]" id="hobby" data-provide="typeahead"> 
                   <input type="hidden" name="hobbyid[]" id="hobbyid" value=""/> 
                 </div>
               </div>';
```

now, when users click on add more fields, then the form is actually get added with all the input fields, but here the bootstrap typeahead didn't worked.

so I tried the below code after reading and searching on GOOGLE.

```
 var hobby_typeahead = $('<input type="text" class="typeahead span10" name="hobby[]" id="hobby" data-provide="typeahead"> <input type="hidden" name="hobbyid[]" id="hobbyid" value=""/>');
 $current_row.append(hobby_typeahead);
```

after this, my dynamic fields started showing me the bootstrap typeahead suggestions..

But, the main problem I am getting is to render the input fields under the bootstrap div ex: control-group, control-label and controls div.

Actually I am looking something like below:

```
 wrapper += '<div class="control-group"> 
                 <label class="control-label">Hobby</label> 
                 <div class="controls"> 
                   '+ hobby_typeahead +'
                   <input type="hidden" name="hobbyid[]" id="hobbyid" value=""/> 
                 </div>
               </div>';
```

I understand this will print object [Object] etc..

I would like to know, how I could attach it within the div's, I could do it by declaring something like this:

```
  $control_group = $('<div class="control-group"></div>');

  $control_label = $('<label class="control-label">Hobby</label>');

  $controls = $('<div class="controls"></div>');
  $controls.append($hobby_typeahead);

  $control_group.append($control_label);
  $control_group.append($controls);

  $current_row.append($control_group);
```

But as I have 4 fields with typeahead suggestion and 6 normal fields, is there any smart way to do it, I don't want to go the long way above.

Thanks in advance, any help or suggestion would be really great help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I created it, to fit in my eyes, this is not the complete solution to fit in my requirement

I have a different and fully working copy with me, I thought posting it here, will add helpful resource for others.

```
    var $span6 = $('<div class="span6"></div>');
    var $hidden_count = $('<input type="hidden" name="count[]"  value="' + count + '"/>');
    var $widget_box = $('<div class="widget-box"><div class="widget-title"> <span class="fa"> <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> </span> <h5>Add User - ' + count + '</h5><button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" id="remove">Remove</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" id="add">Add</button></div>');
    var $widget_content = $('<div class="widget-content nopadding"></div>');

    $span6.append($hidden_count);
    $span6.append($widget_box);


    var $inputs = {
        'First Name':'<input class="span10" type="text" name="firstname[]" id="firstname">',
        'Last Name':'<input class="span10" type="text" name="lastname[]" id="lastname">',
        'Gender':'<select class="span10" name="gender[]" id="gender"> <option value="Male">Male</option> <option value="Female">Female</option> </select>',
        'Email Address':'<input class="span10" type="email" name="email[]" id="email">',
        'Password':'<input class="span10" type="password" name="password[]" id="password" autocomplete="new-password">',
        'Hobbies':'<input type="text" class="typeahead span10" name="hobby[]" id="hobby" data-provide="typeahead">'
    };


    for(var $k in $inputs){
        var $control_group = $('<div class="control-group"></div>');
        var $control_label = $('<label class="control-label">'+$k+'</label>');
        var $controls = $('<div class="controls"></div>');

        var $input = $($inputs[$k]);
        $input.typeahead({
            source: function (query, process) {
                return $.get('get-hobbies?src=typeahead&q='+query, function (data) {
                    return process(JSON.parse(data));
                });
            }
        });
        $controls.append($input);

        $control_group.append($control_label);
        $control_group.append($controls);
        $widget_content.append($control_group);
    }

    $span6.append($widget_content);
    $current_row.append($span6);
```